# Validar entrada con cin

Tags: c++, io

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
int a = 12;
cin >> a;
```

La idea es ingresar un valor para `a` que sea válido para los valores de tipo `int`. El problema es que si ingreso valores incorrectos (por ejemplo de tipo `char`) el programa no valida esa entrada, pero hace que **`a` tome el valor de 0**, cuando debería conservar el valor preestablecido( en este caso 12) hasta que se introduzca un valor adecuado.

He probado aplicar métodos relacionados `cin.ingnore()` y eliminar la entrada de buffer, pero mi variable sigue tomando el valor de 0.

- ¿Cómo se puede validar la entrada para una variable, sin que se cambie su valor original?

Comment: Podrías utilizar una variable "auxiliar" y dependiendo el resultado QUE OBTENGAS en la variable "auxiliar" reemplazas a la variable "a" o caso contrario la dejas intacta.

Answer (score 2):

Las entradas ya están validando, otra cosa es que no suceda como tu esperas.

Si tu tienes un código tal que:

```
int a = 888, c = 999;
std::string b;

std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c;
```

Ante una entrada tipo

```
1Hola2
```

El programa devolverá lo siguiente:

```
1
Hola
2
```

Esto es así porque la lectura del entero finaliza cuando `cin` se encuentra con un caracter que se corresponde con un dígito numérico. La lectura del `b`, en cambio, leerá caracteres hasta que se encuentre con un separador (espacio, salto de línea, ...)

Sin embargo, si la entrada al código anterior la cambiamos a

```
Hola 12
```

El programa ahora nos devolverá lo siguiente:

```
0

999
```

Es decir, el programa únicamente ha modificado la primera variable. ¿Por qué se produce este comportamiento?

Como te he comentado, `cin` hace una validación de las entradas. Cuando le toca leer un número y el primer caracter a leer no es convertible a número entonces `cin` genera un error y se bloquea hasta que reinicies el error.

En nuestro caso, el programa ha intentado leer un número para almacenarlo en `a` y, sin embargo, el primer caracter que se encuentra es `H`. A partir de este punto `cin` se bloquea y **ya no procesa más entradas**.

Para desbloquear `cin` basta, como hemos dicho, con reiniciar el error.

Corrigiendo el problema el programa podría quedar tal que así:

```
int a = 888, c = 999;
std::string b;

std::cin >> a;
std::cin.clear();
std::cin >> b >> c;
std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c;
```

Si lo ejecutamos ahora obtendremos la siguiente salida:

```
0
Hola
12
```

Vemos como ahora, `cin` sí que ha leído la cadena y el número que le sigue.

Lo que suele pasar es que a nosotros como programadores de la interfaz, nos interesa que todas las variables estén correctamente inicializadas. Si el usuario introduce un valor erróneo solemos mostrar un mensaje de error a la espera que el usuario introduzca una entrada válida. En estos casos es conveniente limpiar el buffer de entrada. Si no hacemos esto el programa entrará en un bucle sin fin ya que el primer caracter que se encontrará será siempre la `H`, que no es convertible a número:

```
int a = 888, c = 999;
std::string b;

std::cout << "Introduce un numero:";
while( !(std::cin >> a) )
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Numero no valido. Introduce un numero: ";
}
std::cin >> b >> c;
```

Con esto ya forzamos al usuario a introducir un número válido antes de pasar a leer el resto de variables.

Así que, como ves, `cin` sí que hace una validación de los datos de entrada. Lo que sucede es que a tí esa validación no te sirve, por lo que tienes que implementar una propia.

Hay varias formas de resolver el problema y una de ellas pasa por leer una cadena de texto y analizar dicha cadena para saber si su contenido cumple con nuestros requisitos:

```
std::string a;
std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Introduce un numero:";
while( !std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), ::isdigit) )
{
  std::cout << "Numero no valido. Introduce un numero: ";
  std::cin >> a;
}

std::cout << "Numero introducido: " << a;
```

Ahora bien, resulta que tras la validación nuestro número maravilloso está almacenado en forma de cadena de caracteres... aquí tenemos que idear alguna forma de converir esa cadena en el tipo de dato que nos interesa.

Para este caso concreto, dado que el contenido de `a` es un entero, podemos usar `stringstream`:

```
std::string a;
std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Introduce un numero:";
while( !std::all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), ::isdigit) )
{
  std::cout << "Numero no valido. Introduce un numero: ";
  std::cin >> a;
}

int numero;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << a;
ss >> numero;
std::cout << "Numero: " << numero;
```

Si la entrada fuese más compleja y resulta que no podemos apoyarnos en las utilidades de alto nivel que nos proporciona la STL entonces tendremos que mancharnos las manos y programar nuestro propio sistema de conversión.